# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname exception for SOAP WCF Web Service from Android emulator

Tags: java, android, .net, wcf, iis

I implemented a WCF SOAP service (.Net 4) and I am invoking the service from an Android emulator in Eclipse. My service is deployed in IIS 7 as a Web application. The Web service client on the android does an HTTP POST with the SOAP message.

When I invoke the Web service from the android emulator through Eclipse, I am getting a FileNotFoundException. The error input stream gives me the following exception:

```
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

When I invoke my SOAP Web service from the wcftestclient, the request is successfully processed. 
Also, when I use Apache common tcpmon from the Android emulator client, the SOAP Web service request is successfully processed.

It is only when I setup the Android emulator to access the WCF SOAP Web service directly, I get this exception. I have configured the WCF SOAP Web service as a Web site in IIS and I am accessing it through the IP address/port (`http://<myIPAddress>:<myPortNumber>/MyService.svc?wsdl`).

I setup my HttopURLConnection as follows in my Android client:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", this.getSOAPAction());
connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "base_urlforwebservices like - xyz.net");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "None");
connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "android");
```

I tried taking out `setDoOutput(true)` and `setDoInput(true)` and I also tried setting up authorization credentials in the connection properties:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userCredentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

and it didn't make any difference.

In my Android.manifest file, I added the following settings:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

but that didn't make a difference either.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you run WCF from visual studio ? if so it's only limited to local host 
there are two solutions:

1. if from visual studio notepad %USERPROFILE%\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config  and change the binding from for eaxmpe ":21433:localhost" to  ":21422:" now you should be able to access it from android (10.0.2.2)
2. Deploy the WCF service to IIS
3. mae a proxy on the localhost(pc) and use --http-proxy in android run configuration under target